# Adding a public function to a json object?

Tags: php, json, class

Since php treats a json_decoded string like an object, is there a way to extend that object?

For instance is there a way to take this;

```
$users = json_decode('[{"id":101,"name":"Ken Blank"},{"id":102,"name":"Steve Blank"},{"id":103,"name":"Scott Blank"},{"id":104,"name":"Tim Blank"}]');
```

and extend it, something like;

```
class extended_class extends ___
{
    public function test(){
        echo("test");
    }
}
```

or is there another way to add public functions to a json defined object?

Comment: I believe this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This isn't really a sane thing to want to do. That you're trying to do it indicates you should rethink your solution to whatever your problem is.

Comment: It's more of a curiosity thing.  If it were possible/practical, I would use it as an object definition shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

Php lets you dynamically add properites to an object:

```
    $users = json_decode('{"id":101,"name":"Ken Blank"}');
    $users->test = function(){
        echo("test");
    };

    $users->test();
```

Note that the json in my example is an object, as your title suggests.
However as pointed out by the commentor below, the json string in your question is actually for an array of objects, and you cannot add a property to an array.

Comment: @Jens-AndréKoch edited, the users question suggested a json object, which i didnt bother to check. And yes i missed a semicolon!